# React Hook Form With React AsyncSelect failed to load options

Tags: reactjs

**Updated, remove `options` props**

Still failed.

**File 2:  note.form-master.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";
import UserDataService from "../../../services/user.service";

const NoteFormMaster = ({ register, control, errors }) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState();

  const loadOptions = (inputText) => {

    // Axios here
    UserDataService.getUserList(inputText)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data.map((user) => ({
          value: user.id,
          label: user.username,
        }));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  };

  const handleInputChange = (selectedUser) => {
    if (selectedUser) {
      setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-group col-md-6">
    <label htmlFor="shareWith">Share With</label>
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name="shareWith"
      id="shareWith"
      as={
        <AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          isMulti
          isClearable
          loadOptions={(v) => loadOptions(v)}
          defaultOptions={[]}
          onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      }
      // render={(props) => (
      //   <AsyncSelect
      //     cacheOptions
      //     isMulti
      //     isClearable
      //     loadOptions={(v) => loadOptions(v)}
      //     defaultOptions={[]}
      //     onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      //   />
      // )}
    />
     </div>
  );
};

export default NoteFormMaster;
```

After a whole day try to solved this React Hook Form, I decide to ask here because I am still failed.
I use the react hook form as follows.
I made it into two files to make it easier to read.

The problem is, the **AsyncSelect** `option` does not appear when the `axios response` succeeds. Here's my source code:

**File 1:  note.create.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import NoteDataService from "../../../services/note.service";
import NoteFormMaster from "./note.form-master";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const NoteCreate = (props) => {
  const { register, control, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      shareWith: [],
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
      // Some logic here
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        
         // Load form master
        <NoteFormMaster register={register} control={control} errors={errors} />

        <div className="row mt-4">
          <div className="col">
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="float-right">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default NoteCreate;
```

**File 2:  note.form-master.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";
import UserDataService from "../../../services/user.service";

const NoteFormMaster = ({ register, control, errors }) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState();
  const [suggestion, setSuggestion] = useState([]);

  const loadOptions = (inputText) => {

    // Axios here
    UserDataService.getUserList(inputText)
      .then((response) => {
        let options = response.data.map((user) => ({
          value: user.id,
          label: user.username,
        }));
        setSuggestion(options);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  };

  const handleInputChange = (selectedUser) => {
    if (selectedUser) {
      setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-group col-md-6">
    <label htmlFor="shareWith">Share With</label>
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name="shareWith"
      id="shareWith"
      as={
        <AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          isMulti
          isClearable
          options={suggestion}
          loadOptions={(v) => loadOptions(v)}
          defaultOptions={[]}
          onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      }
      // render={(props) => (
      //   <AsyncSelect
      //     cacheOptions
      //     isMulti
      //     isClearable
      //     loadOptions={(v) => loadOptions(v)}
      //     defaultOptions={[]}
      //     onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      //   />
      // )}
    />
     </div>
  );
};

export default NoteFormMaster;
```

I've checked the axios results using `console.log (suggestion)`

The result:

```
[
    {
        "value": 44,
        "label": "Dzil"
    },
    {
        "value": 190,
        "label": "gmaildzil"
    }
]
```

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: Why do you have an `options` prop? That seems wrong.

Comment: AsyncSelect  will use promise resolver or callback value as options, no need to manually store and set "suggestion"

Comment: Thanks all, at my first try, I am not using ```options``` at all.

Comment: Event I delete ```options``` is still not works.

Answer (score 1):

As i wrote in my comment:

```
const loadOptions = (inputText) => {

    // return promise here.
    return UserDataService.getUserList(inputText)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data.map((user) => ({
          value: user.id,
          label: user.username,
        }));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  };

// The defaultOptions prop determines "when" your remote request is initially fired.
<AsyncSelect
  cacheOptions
  isMulti
  isClearable
  loadOptions={(v) => loadOptions(v)}
  defaultOptions
  onInputChange={handleInputChange}
/>
```

Comment: I have try this way before your suggestion, it`s still failed. Weird of React.

Comment: Instead of  loadOptions={(v) => loadOptions(v)} can you try  loadOptions={loadOptions} @FadlyDzil

Comment: You can try modify `defaultOptions={[]}` to `defaultOptions` @FadlyDzil

Comment: @ruoyanli It will makes when page load, loading animation is show. But still not showing those options

Comment: I am thinking, is this about styling ? I am using react bootsrap

Comment: Maybe. There is a worked example for comparison: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-asyncselect-j5vy8

Comment: Ok, thanks. Btw, My react version is 17, which is your exmaple is quite aboslute 16

Comment: it doesn't matter, using v17 still work well.

Answer (score 1):

In your hook define selectedOption constant

```
const [selectedOption , setSelectedOption ] = useState(null)
```

Try this setting in you Async Tag

```
<AsyncSelect
                                placeholder="Select ..."
                                defaultOptions
                                cacheOptions
                                onInputChange={onInputChange}
                                loadOptions={loadOptions}
                                onChange={changeSelectedOption}
                                value={selectedOption}
                                />
```

Make sure that your loadOptions function should return options

```
const loadOptions = (inputText) => {

    // Axios here
    UserDataService.getUserList(inputText)
      .then((response) => {
        let options = response.data.map((user) => ({
          value: user.id,
          label: user.username,
        }));
        setSuggestion(options);
        return options;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        return null
      });
  };
```

Add you on Change function to get selected value from dropdown

```
const changeSelectedOption = (selectedOption) => {
        selectedOption = (selectedOption == null) ? {} : selectedOption ;
        setSelectedOption(selectedOption )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, After I see in [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-asyncselect-j5vy8?file=/src/index.js:415-550) , Promise need resolve, so in axios we need the return value, like this:

```
const loadOptions = (inputText) => {
    const len = inputText.length;

    // We need to tell user must input more than 3 characters
    if (len > 3) {
      return UserDataService.getUserList(inputText)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.data.map((user) => ({
            value: user.id,
            label: user.username,
          }));

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
  };
```

Oke, Please Vote. Bye.